# my android studio can`t find compile method(com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, android-constraintlayout

i have this problem in Android Studio and i added this in build.gradle file but i have that problem.

> Error:(13, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

     repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

     }
     dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        compile'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'                                
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
     }
    }

    allprojects {
     repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
     }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) Try making messages/output stand out as a *block quote*: precede each line with `> ` (or mark it and use the button or keyboard-short-cut in the post editor). (The indentation in the *code block* looks off: conventionally, nested blocks are indented one more level. If `// Top-level build file …` is to be part of that code block, precede it (and the following blank line) with another four blanks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove** this line:

```
compile'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
```

You **can't add** the dependencies in the **top-level** file also you can not use this dependency in the `buildscript` block.

Answer (score 0):

Beta 4 is an old version. Try using `1.0.2` instead:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```